# Flutter - ListView.builder - can we add a variable to use as "counter" beside "index"?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

My question might seem badly formulated but I just couldn't find a clearer way to put it.
Here's the situation :

- I have a list of info contained in a list called "carnetList" (see code below).
- I am supposed to display only the info for which the parameter "thematic" is false.
  This works fine. However, I need to number the info that I am displaying. I used "index" for that "List n°1 etc...". But since it skips some elements (thematic == true), then I get "List n°1... then List n°4 etc...".

Is there a way to add another "counter" ? that I could use instead of "index" which would actually correspond to the number of elements displayed ?

Here's the code :

```
ListView.builder(
            cacheExtent: 2000,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            itemCount: uD.userInfo.carnetList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].thematic == false
                  ? CarnetListCard2(
                      index: index,  **// This is where I used Index to display "List n+$index" in the widget.** 
                      taille: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].carnetWordId.length,
                      titre: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].titre,
                      dateCreation: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].creation,
                      dateModification:
                          uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].modification,
                      test: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].test,
                      dateTest: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].testDate,)                             
                  : Container();
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're close, but you do not want to filter the list during the item build. If you make sure your list is filtered before passing it to the listview you'll get the result you want. the simplest way to do this:

```dart
final list = D.userInfo.carnetList.where((carnet) => !carnet.thematic).toList();

return ListView.builder(
 itemCount: list.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   final carnet = list[index];
   final number = index + 1;
   ...
 }
)
```

or if you don't want to work with a seperate list

```dart
ListView(
  children: D.userInfo.carnetList.where((carnet) => !carnet.thematic).map((item) {
   return ... // your widget
 }).toList();
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) This will work. The only drawback is the added complexity to manage the filtered list : user can "delete" elements, add others etc... I thought of creating a parallel list of "index" containing the index of the elements that need to be displayed... but same thing, I believe it would create risks of problems linked to users acting on the list's content...

Comment: updated the answer with an example that doesn't require a seperate list. I would not recommend this however as your doing a lot of data and state management right in your UI

Comment: I agree with you. I may have to rethink my list management in my provider file and filter it before displaying as you suggested. Thanks again for your help. Though the "ListView" solution looks tempting ;) Is it that serious to do a little "data" management in the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a counter and whenever the condition is true, you increase it.

It will work as the `index of the items that are actually good for me`.

```
int _itemsCounter = 0;

ListView.builder(
            cacheExtent: 2000,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            itemCount: uD.userInfo.carnetList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].thematic == false) _itemsCounter++;

              return uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].thematic == false
                  ? CarnetListCard2(
                      index: index,  **// This is where I used Index to display "List n+$index" in the widget.** 
                      taille: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].carnetWordId.length,
                      titre: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].titre,
                      dateCreation: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].creation,
                      dateModification:
                          uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].modification,
                      test: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].test,
                      dateTest: uD.userInfo.carnetList[index].testDate,)                             
                  : Container();
            },
          ),
```

Just make sure when you use the `_itemsCounter` as index, subtract 1 out of it.

So if 3 items fulfill the condition, this counter will be 3, but the indexes of elements are 0, 1, 2

Comment: This doesn't fully work : if you scroll all the way down the list and then go back up, it rebuilds and counter increases and it shouldn't... so the indexes get all wrong...